# Adding items in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

I was preparing to create a website using PHPMyAdmin and I bang into a problem : I don't understant why my code does things I don't want.

This is the code to create the tables and some random entries :

```
create table stud (
    matrnr int primary key,
    pname Varchar(30) not null
);

create table prof (
    persnr int primary key,
    pname Varchar(50) not null
);

create table vorl (
    vorlnr int primary key,
    titel varchar(50),
    prof int references prof(persnr) on delete set null
);

create table prüfen (
    stud int references stud(matrnr) on delete cascade,
    vorl int references vorl(vorlnr),
    prof int references prof(persnr) on delete set null,
    note float,
    primary key(Stud, vorl)
);

insert into stud values
(1, 'G'),
(2, 'F'),
(3, 'C');

insert into Prof values
(1, 'M'),
(2, 'L'),
(3, 'M');

insert into vorl values 
(1, 'Info1', 'M'),
(1, 'Info2', 'L'),
(1, 'Info3', 'M');

insert into prüfen values
(1, 1, 1, 2.0),
(1, 2, 1, 1.7),
(2, 3, 2, 2.3);
```

At this position I tried

```
Insert into prüfen values (3, 1, 4, 2.0);
```

but the was still only 3 lines in the table `prüfen`.

Any help is wellcome.
Have a good week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your final insert failed because it references a professor with a `prof` ID of 4, which does not exist in the `prof` table.

If you look closely at your definition for the `prüfen` table, this will be more clear:

```
create table prüfen (
    stud int references stud(matrnr) on delete cascade,
    vorl int references vorl(vorlnr),
    prof int references prof(persnr) on delete set null,
    note float,
    primary key(Stud, vorl)
);
```

The field `prof` is a foreign key into the `prof` table.  MySQL will require that this field references a professor which actually exists.  It does not in the case of your final insert.  To get around this error, you could create such a professor, e.g.

```
insert into Prof values
(4, 'M');
```

You didn't report an error in your question, which seems off to me.  Maybe you failed to mention it, or perhaps your error reporting is turned off for some reason.

Comment: Wouldn't there be an error displayed?  OP didn't say anything about errors.

Comment: @RickS Yes, I would expect an error just about anywhere.  Maybe the OP failed to mention it, or perhaps his error reporting is turned off.  My explanation is the only thing which comes to mind at the moment.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. Now I understand what was actually happening. I reajusted it so now it's working fine. Thank you very much ;)